# Cannot serialize my game stats

Tags: c#, serialization, save, unity-game-engine

Well i am trying to save my Game Stats using system serializable but i am not being able to do it i have two scripts one named "Stats" and another named "SaveLoad" in the "Stats" i have my serializables and in the "SaveLoad" i have my saving and loading script i followed the instructions here

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934

But since i am a begginer with this stuff and my seriazable data differs i am having issues on saving it.

My "Stats"

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
[System.Serializable]
public class Stats : MonoBehaviour {

public static int coins = 0;
public static int totalcoins = 0;
public static int score = 0;

public static int personalbest = 0;
public static float UmbrellaSpeed = 0.1f;
public static float currentumbdur = 500;

public static int CarrotSpawnRateLVL = 1;
public static float CarrotSpawnRate = 60f;
public static int CarrotSpawnRateUpgradeCost = 15;


public static int UmbrellaDurabilityLVL = 1;
public static float UmbrellaDurability = 500;
public static int UmbrellaDurabilityUpgradeCost = 30;

public static int UmbrellaSizeLVL = 1;
public static float UmbrellaSize = 0f;
public static int UmbrellaSizeUpgradeCost = 25;


public static int CarrotEffectLVL = 1;
public static float CarrotEffect = 20;
public static int CarrotEffectUpgradeCost = 25;


public static int HealthRegenLVL = 1;
public static float HealthRegenTime = 4f;
public static int HealthRegenCost = 100;


public static int BuyTreesCost = 250;

public static int Tree1Bought = 0;
public static float Tree1Size = 0;
public static int Tree1SizeLVL = 1;
public static int Tree1SizeUpgradeCost = 50;

public static int Tree2Bought = 0;
public static float Tree2Size = 0;
public static int Tree2SizeLVL = 1;
public static int Tree2SizeUpgradeCost = 50;

public static int Tree3Bought = 0;
public static float Tree3Size =0;
public static int Tree3SizeLVL = 1;
public static int Tree3SizeUpgradeCost = 50;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating ("AddCoins", 4.0f, 2.0f);
    InvokeRepeating ("AddScore", 1.5f, 1.5f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (score > personalbest) {
        personalbest = score;
    }
    //Debug.Log (" " + coins);
}

void AddCoins (){       
    if (BunnyScript.BunnyAlive == true) {
        coins += 1;

    }
}

void AddScore (){
    if (BunnyScript.BunnyAlive == true) {
        score += 1;
    }
}

}
```

And my "SaveLoad" script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; 
using System.IO;

public static class SaveLoad {
public static List<Stats> savedGames = new List<Stats>();

public static void Save (){
    savedGames.Add(Stats);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd");
    bf.Serialize(file, SaveLoad.savedGames);
    file.Close();
}

public static void Load (){
    if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd")) {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd", FileMode.Open);
        SaveLoad.savedGames = (List<Stats>)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Also if its possible to not save currentumbdur and coins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not serialize a MonoBehaviour class for storing data, there is so much below that you cannot see in this type that it is just wrong.

Also, you have a list of stats object but it is only containing static value so all your Stats objects have same content.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

public class Stats : MonoBehaviour 
{
    StatContainer stats = new StatContainer();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
       InvokeRepeating ("AddCoins", 4.0f, 2.0f);
       InvokeRepeating ("AddScore", 1.5f, 1.5f);
    }

     // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        this.stats.Update();
    }

    void AddCoins (){       
       stats.AddCoins();
    }

    void AddScore (){
       stats.AddScore();
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class StatContainer
{
    public int coins = 0;
    public int totalcoins = 0;
    public int score = 0;

    public int personalbest = 0;
    public float UmbrellaSpeed = 0.1f;
    public float currentumbdur = 500;

    public  int CarrotSpawnRateLVL = 1;
    public float CarrotSpawnRate = 60f;
    public int CarrotSpawnRateUpgradeCost = 15;

    // and the rest

    public void Update(){
       if (statscore > personalbest) {
             personalbest = score;
       }
    }
}
```

Now you can serialize the StatContainer in the same manner you were.
Because there is no static method anymore, each StatContainr on each Stats component is unique and not sharing anything with others.

And bonus, you can even perform unit test more easily with StatContainer, but that is another topic.